Can modal “can” express future meaning?
Does this sentence in bold with “can” instead of “will be able to” sound natural to native English speakers?
“This is the only port still under our control. If the enemy occupies it in their next attack in December, they can cut off the supply line to our capital at the beginning of 2025.”

sounds natural to me

this feels less cluttered ... If the enemy occupies it in December, they can cut off the supply line to our capital at the beginning of 2025.

Thanks for replying. Are you a native speaker of American English? @jsotola

Cross-posting with ELU https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/627493/can-i-use-can-here

This is the third time you've asked the same question.

I. "can" or "will be able to":
OP asked about the use of "can" for future tense:

If the enemy occupies it in their next attack in December, they can cut off the supply line to our capital at the beginning of 2025.

Both  "can" and "will be able to" can express future ability, but they differ in how they are used:
II. Talking about Abilities

"Can" applies to the present and future to express general ability or possibility.
.
"Be able to" works in all tenses to express ability and is often used to emphasize specific situations.
.
Examples:

I can teach English.
I was able to teach English.
I am able to teach English.
I will be able to teach English.


III. Application to OP's sentence:

"Can" emphasizes general ability or possibility, implying the enemy will have the capability.
"Will be able to" emphasizes future ability more explicitly, highlighting the cause-effect relationship tied to the specific event.

While  "can" is grammatically correct and conveys the necessary meaning, "will be able to" is better suited for the formal and strategic tone of the military context.
